# React-Cannot use context.router to redirect page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I wanted to build a my react/react-router/flux application. 
I want to redirect user to login page when user enter the secret link (like admin page)

Here is admin component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
render() {
if (!adminLogin){
this.context.router.transitionTo('/login');
}
return (    
  <div className="wrapper">
        <Navbar />
        <SidebarLeft />
            <div className="content-wrapper">
            {this.props.children}
             </div>
        <Footer />
  </div>
 );}}
 App.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.func
 };
 export default App;
```

But, I have a proplem with react context

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'transitionTo' of undefined
at App.render (App.js:8:5)
at [objectObject].ReactCompositeComponentMixin._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (D:\web\MVCmodel\library\lib\node_modules\react\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:587:34)
at [object Object].ReactCompositeComponentMixin._renderValidatedComponent (D:\web\MVCmodel\library\lib\node_modules\react\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:607:32)
at [object Object].wrapper [as _renderValidatedComponent] (D:\web\MVCmodel\library\lib\node_modules\react\lib\ReactPerf.js:66:21)
at [object Object].ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (D:\web\MVCmodel\library\lib\node_modules\react\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:220:30)
at [object Object].wrapper [as mountComponent] (D:\web\MVCmodel\library\lib\node_modules\react\lib\ReactPerf.js:66:21)
at Object.ReactReconciler.mountComponent (D:\web\MVCmodel\library\lib\node_modules\react\lib\ReactReconciler.js:37:35)
at [object Object].ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (D:\web\MVCmodel\library\lib\node_modules\react\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:225:34)
at [object Object].wrapper [as mountComponent] (D:\web\MVCmodel\library\lib\node_modules\react\lib\ReactPerf.js:66:21)
at D:\web\MVCmodel\library\lib\node_modules\react\lib\ReactServerRendering.js:42:38
at ReactServerRenderingTransaction.Mixin.perform (D:\web\MVCmodel\library\lib\node_modules\react\lib\Transaction.js:136:20)
at Object.renderToString (D:\web\MVCmodel\library\lib\node_modules\react\lib\ReactServerRendering.js:40:24)
at D:\web\MVCmodel\library\lib\server.js:326:27
at D:\web\MVCmodel\library\lib\node_modules\react-router\lib\match.js:58:5
at D:\web\MVCmodel\library\lib\node_modules\react-router\lib\useRoutes.js:120:15
at done (D:\web\MVCmodel\library\lib\node_modules\react-router\lib\AsyncUtils.js:49:19)
```

I have no ideas for this problem and don't know how to fix it.Please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Router is not a function, it's an object.

this

```
 App.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.func
 };
```

should be

```
 App.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object
 };
```

As you can see in the [React-Router documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/12-navigating)

**-- Edited --**

You can also achieve that using history instead of router.

```
App.contextTypes = {
        history: React.PropTypes.object
     };
```

and use it like this

```
this.context.history.pushState(null, '/login');
```

Comment: I changed it.But it didn't work and alert with same message! :(

Comment: try adding a constructor and check if the second parameter, which is the context has a router prop

Comment: I try adding `constructor(props) { super(props);}`, but the result is similar. I don't know why

Comment: I also try adding `console.log(this.context.router);` inside render(). But result is `undefine`.

Comment: what's your react router version?

Comment: `react-router:1.0.3` and `react: 0.14.7`

Comment: that react-router version doesn't have the router in the context, you have to update it to >= 2.0.0-rc2, otherwise you'll have to use history instead of router.

Comment: I saw your edited post. This broblem is solve but the link isn't redirect to login page

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using the browserHistory (pushState API) within react-router. I would use the push function of it and let the router transition to your component:

```
var Router = require('react-router');
Router.browserHistory.push('/login');
```

or in ES6 Syntax:

```
import {browserHistory} from ('react-router');
browserHistory.push('/login');
```

So with that in mind, your complete code should more look like this:

```
import React, {PropTypes, Component} from 'react';
import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    if (!adminLogin) {
      browserHistory.push('/login');
    }
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <Navbar />
        <SidebarLeft />
        <div className="content-wrapper">
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```